# RabbitVCS on Nautilus 3.30 not opening logger and browser

Tags: python, git, svn, gnome, nautilus

I've got the RabbitVCS-nautilus extension installed with its dependency pygtk. The extension runs with Python2 but it throws an error that pygtk is not installed in the console.

It is weird because when I open a python2 console, the module can be imported but it gives an error that it cannot when running in Nautilus. It only gives the error when I try to open the browser or logger but the folder and file emblems are working fine.

Also some other extensions are breaking and they used to work. Any idea what might be the cause since the last update?

I am using Debian with gnome 3.30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you checked if you have a PYTHON global environment variable? Please look at the [pull request](https://github.com/rabbitvcs/rabbitvcs/pull/247) I made.

Comment: Got it! Apparently my global PYTHON variable was pointing towards a python3 installation, and the `util/helper.py` file from rabbitVCS was overriding the executing python2 env with the global PYTHON env (which had the wrong version). Thanks!